# Angular 4 inputs form initial with null , not empty string

Tags: angular

form.html

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <input ngModel=null name="finish_date" type="text" class="form-control">
</form>
{{form.value | json}}
```

form.value

```
{"finish_date": "null"}
```

finish_date is "null" string, not null.

I want input value default is null not empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `[(ngModel)]` and use **`yourObj.finish_date`**

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <input [(ngModel)]=yourObj.finish_date name="finish_date" type="text" class="form-control">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can either use two-way binding [(ngModel)] or one way using
>   [ngModal] with your object

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <input [(ngModel)]="finish_date" name="finish_date" type="text" class="form-control">
</form>

{{form.value | json}}
```

[**`Working Demo`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-test)